# Find columns with different types across supposedly equivalent databases

Tags: sql-server

Each of our clients has a database with their own data. Each database should have exactly the same structure. How can I find columns whose datatype has been changed, where the table name and column name is the same but the datatype is not? Is there an SQL query that can do this?

Comment: Did the databases all start from a single golden image (e.g. a backup file that was restored), or were they created from scripts?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I regret I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both databases can be restored to the same server, you can compare the two sets of system catalog views to determine the differences:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.name,
    ColumnName = c.name,
    TypeName = ty.name,
    TableName2 = t2.name,
    ColumnName2 = c2.name,
    TypeName2 = ty2.name
FROM DB1.sys.columns c
INNER JOIN DB1.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN DB1.sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
INNER JOIN DB2.sys.tables t2 ON t.name = t2.Name
INNER JOIN DB2.sys.columns c2 ON c2.object_id = t2.object_id AND c.name = c2.name
INNER JOIN DB2.sys.types ty2 ON c2.system_type_id = ty2.system_type_id
WHERE
    c.system_type_id <> c2.system_type_id
```

Of course, you can add more columns from the `sys.columns` catalog view, e.g. `precision` and `scale` for types like `DECIMAL(18,2)`, or `max_length` for string-based types (like `VARCHAR(50)` etc.) - adapt this base query as needed

Comment: Thanks @marc_s! Is there any way to enter the database name only once?

Comment: @MichaelSandler: no I don't think so - you need the fully qualified `db.schema.objectname` notation for all catalog views involved here...

Comment: Well, I have forty databases on the server which I would like to check for type differences and I am looking to make it easier on myself :-)

Comment: @MichaelSandler: if you execute the query while you're "on" database `DB1`, then you don't need to have those three prefixes. And you could probably generate those SQL queries for each of the 40 databases you need to check against, and then execute them one by one (possibly storing results into a table and then reporting on all discrepancies after having checked all databases)

Answer (score 2):

Take snapshots of the schemas and use [REDGATE's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CPudiK2exrECFURfTAodKGcAwg) utility.

Or export the schemas to text and use [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Atlantis SchemaInspector](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/schemainspector/) is good tool for this purpose.

**EDIT:**
If you want SQL query, you need the available both databases in one query.
So the databases must be on one sql server instance OR the sql server instances must are available as linked server.

Query:

```
SELECT
    *
/* source database >>> */
FROM [SourceDatabase].[sys].[schemas] AS S_A
INNER JOIN [SourceDatabase].[sys].[objects] AS O_A
    ON [O_A].[schema_id] = [S_A].[schema_id]
INNER JOIN [SourceDatabase].[sys].[columns] AS C_A
    ON [C_A].[object_id] = [O_A].[object_id]
/* <<< source database */
/* target database >>> */
LEFT JOIN [TargetDatabase].[sys].[schemas] AS S_B
    ON [S_B].[name] = [S_A].[name]
LEFT JOIN [TargetDatabase].[sys].[objects] AS O_B
    ON [O_B].[schema_id] = [S_B].[schema_id]
        AND [O_B].[name] = [O_A].[name]
LEFT JOIN [TargetDatabase].[sys].[columns] AS C_B
    ON [C_B].[object_id] = [O_B].[object_id]
        AND [C_B].[name] = [C_A].[name]
/* <<< target database */
WHERE [C_B].[column_id] IS NULL
    OR [C_B].[system_type_id] <> [C_A].[system_type_id]
```